# How to properly implement and close sleeping thread in a Windows DLL

Tags: multithreading, dll

I have a native Windows DLL written in C. This DLL is designed to be loaded (injected) in different Windos processes. This DLL creates some working threads that look like this:

```
while(1) {
    // do work
    Sleep(few secs);
}
```

The problem is if the process exits and DLL unloads while thread is in Sleep() it will crash the process when it comes back from Sleep (thread will try to execute code that is not there). I was thinking of using TerminateThread() with the DllUnload handler but MSDN says it should be used in most extreme cases only. For example - my threads use critical sections and the documentation says:

> If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.

How do I cleanly close the thread that is sleeping when the DLL is unloading? Should I redesign my working threads to do work in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an event:

```
HANDLE threadTerminationEvent = CreateEvent(.....);
```

Use `WaitForSingleObject` instead of `Sleep`:

```
while (1)
{
    ...........
    if (WaitForSingleObject(threadTerminationEvent, few secs) != WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        break;
}
// release resources and end thread
```

Wait for the thread to end itself:

```
SetEvent(threadTerminationEvent); // “please, die”
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
```

Comment: *Never* use TerminateThread in this case, it is only safe at program shutdown.  Just pass INFINITE to WFSO.

Comment: I used INFINITE in past and got hangups when something went wrong with the thread. Isn't it more practical to unsafely kill the thread after ~30 seconds than freezing forever and making user to kill the whole process anyway?

Comment: There's nothing practical about leaking a megabyte of memory and leaving your program in an indetermined state.  That process kill will come later, at a point where you have no clue anymore what actually went wrong.